# Camera zooming by using Bluetooth buttons that act as volume buttons

Tags: bluetooth, camera, zooming

I have a Huawei P30 Pro and this Bluetooth camera shutter. The shutter had dedicated buttons for zooming.

[image]

Sadly, the volume buttons on the P30 just act as a shutter (the zooming buttons on the shutter just send the volume buttons signals too) and there is no customization option in the built-in mobile app to set them for zooming).

I found [Adobe Lightroom](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lightroom&c=apps&hl=en_US)  that lets you use the volume buttons for zooming, but it does not utilise the optical zooming of the phone and the shutter button will stop working (it will be similar to the zooming-out button)

Is there any workaround? Alternatively, any apps that can be installed to take photos instead of the factory app?